# Can you use word "translated" as adjective?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

I am wondering if word *translated* can be used as adjective in the following example.

> I have a translated document.

For me this sounds completely fine, but dictionaries do not provide word *translated* as adjective like [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/translate?q=translated) and [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/translate).

Comment: Obviously, it's fine as you said. Check out this [Google Ngram result](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+translated+*%2Cthe+translated+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Why do dictionaries not list the word as an adjective? Because the past participle of ANY verb can be used adjectivally. `Dice`d onion.  Newly `wash`ed car.  A `blacken`ed reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Translate** is a verb. In your example, it is acting as an adjective.  For example:

*"He translated the book."* - **verb** 
*"This is the translated edition."* - **adjective**

Answer (score 2):

[Participles are used as adjectives](http://rwc.hunter.cuny.edu/reading-writing/on-line/particip.html), both the present participle and the past participle. *Translated* is the past participle of *translate*, so it can be used as adjective too.